# Two asterisks before variable name

Tags: c

While digging in some C source code I found that fragment of code

```
char  **words
```

I know that single asterisk before variable name "points" to pointer, but what is the purpose of those two asterisks ?

Comment: How useful is that? Can anyone give me some simple example ?

Comment: Very very useful, just as useful as a pointer to something that isn't a pointer, e.g. an int or a function.  An extra level of indirection is always a potentially useful

Comment: "What are pointers to pointers good for, in practice? One use is returning pointers from functions, via pointer arguments rather than as the formal return value"
http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html

Take your time and read the entire page ;)

Comment: Assuming you understand what a ``char* word`` is, adding an extra ``*`` and an ``s`` to get ``char** words`` shouldn't be too hard to visualise?

Answer (score 11):

It is a pointer to a pointer.

It is used primarily when you use an array of character strings.

For example: you have `char sample[5][5]`; - this can store 5 strings of length 4;

If you need to pass it to a function, `func(sample)`;

And the function definition of such a function would be `func(char **temp)`;

Comment: a 2d array is not compatible with that function declaration.

Answer (score 7):

```
// your imagination is the limit
char letter;
char *word;        // sequence of letters
char **sentence;   // sequence of words
char ***paragraph; // sequence of sentences
char ****book;     // sequence of paragraphs
char *****library; // sequence of books
```

The data structure is probably not the best to represent the concept: this is just an illustration.

Answer (score -2):

simple dude!
it points to the pointer thats it

**a points to the pointer *a
thats it.

For more information you can google it